# Cannot load variable data into Summernote

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, summernote

I want summernote to display the content if it's exists when loading. But I am unable to load value of a variable into Summernote during it's initialization in codeview.

Here's the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {                
    $('.summernote').on('summernote.init', function () {
      $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.activate');
    }).summernote({
      height: 300,
      placeholder: 'Paste content here...',
      codemirror: { 
        theme: 'monokai'
      }
    }).summernote('code', '<?php echo isset($profiledata["Profile"])?$profiledata["Profile"]:"" ?>');

});

<form>
<div class="form-group">
   <label for="summernote"><strong>Paste the HTML code here:</strong></label>        
   <textarea class="summernote" name="profile" id="profile"> </textarea>        
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I posted the solution that worked for me. However, I welcome any suggestions. Thanks,

Comment: How is this question related to PHP?

Comment: add  data-plugin="summernote" in textarea

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Question edited.

Comment: @NimsPatel Tried. not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The content is not being displayed in codeview mode. So, I used a hack - Deactivated codeview and displayed the content and re-activated the codeview. Here is the solutions that worked for me. However, I welcome any suggestions. Thanks,

```
$(document).ready(function() {                

    $('.summernote').on('summernote.init', function () {
      $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.activate');
    });

    $('#profile').summernote({
      height: 300,
      placeholder: 'Paste content here...',
      codemirror: { 
        theme: 'monokai'
      }
    });

    codeviewOn = $('#profile').summernote('codeview.isActivated');        
    if (codeviewOn) {
  $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.deactivate');
  $('#profile').summernote('code', '<?php echo json_encode($profiledata["Profile"]);?>');
  $('.summernote').summernote('codeview.activate');
}                

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the existing content in Summernote by setting it between the textarea tags.

```
<form>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="summernote"><strong>Paste the HTML code here:</strong></label>        
<textarea class="summernote" name="profile" id="profile"><?php echo 
((isset($yourcontent)) ? '' . $yourcontent . '' : ''); ?></textarea>        
</div>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" 
id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this just shows the content. The text area is gone.